# python arabic encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding

i have a text with windows-1256 encoding. now i want to convert text from arabic(windows-1256) to utf-8

**sample text :**

```
Óæí Ïæã ÈíåÞí
```

**result :**

```
سوي دوم بيهقي
```

i use this code to decode and encod to utf-8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = "Óæí Ïæã ÈíåÞí"
print data.decode("windows-1256", "replace")
print data.encode("windows-1256")
```

that code return this result:

```
أ“أ¦أ­ أڈأ¦أ£ أˆأ­أ¥أ‍أ­
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mohmal2.py", line 5, in <module>
    print data.encode("windows-1256")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1256.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

i found a site that can convert this text:

[http://www.iosart.com](http://www.iosart.com/tools/charset-fixer/?source-text=%C3%93%00%C3%A6%C3%AD%20%C3%8F%C3%A6%C3%A3%20%C3%88%C3%AD%C3%A5%C3%9E%C3%AD%3C&input-encoding=windows-1256)

Comment: `Ó` isn't in Windows-1256. What's your actual question?

Comment: You do have a mojibake, but that's not the right codec. A mis-decoding as windows-1256 of the UTF8 encoded version of your input would look like this: `'ط³ظˆظٹ ط¯ظˆظ… ط¨ظٹظ‡ظ‚ظٹ'`‎

Comment: i have xml response with header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1256"?>`  and i want to parse it !

Comment: Perhaps you have your system configured to expect CP1252 in the console and thus printing CP1256 data is *simply misdisplayed*. I think you need to take several steps back and first learn how to correctly assess what data you have (e.g. don't trust your console, use `repr()` to show you debug information about your data).

Comment: Also, upgrade to Python 3 if you have the chance at all.

Comment: Also, before you continue, teach yourself about the difference between bytes and Unicode text. Start with [*Pragmatic Unicode*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), perhaps also read [*The Absolute Minimum...*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and end with the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you have accidentally decoded the input as Windows-1252.

```
>>> "Óæí Ïæã ÈíåÞí".encode('cp1252').decode('cp1256')
'سوي دوم بيهقي'
```

Comment: Nice catch! I can indeed confirm that the Mojibake can be reproduced with `original.encode('cp1256').decode('cp1252')`.

Comment: i test it but not work !
`>>> "Óæí Ïæã ÈíåÞí".encode('cp1252').decode('cp1256')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @AmirMohsen: you are using **bytes**, so the codec used for that string is going to **depend on your local console settings**, and **already is encoded**. It may well be UTF-8. Use `u"Óæí Ïæã ÈíåÞí"` instead.

Comment: @AmirMohsen: specifically, `str.encode()` must first **decode** to get a `unicode` object that can then be encoded, which is why you get a Unicode**Decode**Error for ASCII.

Comment: I know this is old but I wanted to add to @AmirMohsen 's issue. You can add `encoding='cp1252'` to your file open and it will bypass that error. This data gibberish you're getting is because you saved arabic text as ANSI instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to @josh-lee answer the case for python2.
If you are using python 2, add unicode prefix `u`.

```
>>> u"Óæí Ïæã ÈíåÞí".encode('cp1252').decode('cp1256')
u'\u0633\u0648\u064a \u062f\u0648\u0645 \u0628\u064a\u0647\u0642\u064a'
>>> print _
سوي دوم بيهقي
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Josh Lee's solution, I used this line for reading csv with Farsi(Persian) characters and it worked pretty well:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\FILE PATH\FILE NAME\.csv',encoding='cp1256')
```